# #1226 - User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Tags: php, mysql

By mistake I  did max_questions = 1 . Now mysql is  not working . how to update these settings

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please provide further context for your issue. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This setting is a per hour setting, so you should be able to log in in a short time and update the `mysql.user` table for the user account in question. You can use

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_questions=0 WHERE User='root';
```

setting to 0 is unlimited queries...

Also Read [MySQL Forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,32194,32209#msg-32209)

Comment: But Now I am not able to connect mysql its just showing .
how can i connect mysql and where can i execute this query

Comment: Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1226 - User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Comment: You can run this query directly to you phpmyadmin

Comment: As i open phpmyadmin its just showing this error
Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1226 - User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Comment: run this `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
SELECT @@character_set_client; `

Comment: Where i can run this query please  guide me i can not understand . i am writing localhost/phpmyadmin and its just showing and max query error

Comment: try this `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' 
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0;`

Comment: where to run please tell me ,,,,